# How to move an image in a Grid with the directional keys

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I'm doing a game in a WPF application... For curious people, it's Frogger. So, I want to move an image with the directional keys in a Grid. My code :

```
private void image_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Key == Key.Right)
            {
                Grid.SetRow(frog, 0);
                Grid.SetColumn(frog, 1);
            }

            else if (e.Key == Key.Up)
            {
                Grid.SetRow(frog, 1);
                Grid.SetColumn(frog, 0);
            }

            else if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            {
                Grid.SetRow(frog, -1);
                Grid.SetColumn(frog, 0);
            }

            else if (e.Key == Key.Left)
            {
                Grid.SetRow(frog, 0);
                Grid.SetColumn(frog, -1);
            }
        }
```

My image is "frog". I used the KeyDown event for this part of my code... There is my XAML code :

```
<Image Name="frog" Source="images/18953.png" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="35" Grid.Row="9" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="35" KeyDown="image_KeyDown"/>
```

But nothing works. What is my mistake ??

Comment: `KeyDown` event of what? Post that part also

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image needs to be `Focusable`, set focus on it in `MouseDown`, then you'll receive key events.

```
<Image Name="frog"
       Focusable="True"
       Source="..."
       KeyDown="Frog_OnKeyDown"
       MouseDown="Frog_OnMouseDown"></Image>
```

And in code behind

```
private void Frog_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Right)
    {
        if (Grid.GetColumn(frog) <= Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count - 1)
            Grid.SetColumn(frog, Grid.GetColumn(frog) + 1);
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.Up)
    {
        if (Grid.GetRow(frog) > 0)
            Grid.SetRow(frog, Grid.GetRow(frog) - 1);
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.Down)
    {
        if (Grid.GetRow(frog) <= Grid.RowDefinitions.Count - 1)
            Grid.SetRow(frog, Grid.GetRow(frog) + 1);
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.Left)
    {
        if (Grid.GetColumn(frog) > 0)
            Grid.SetColumn(frog, Grid.GetColumn(frog) - 1);
    }
}

private void Frog_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    frog.Focus();
}
```

Comment: I have an error with Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count... It says that I need a reference for System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.get... It's the same thing with Grid.RowDefinitions.Count...

Comment: So... What can I do ?

Comment: In your grid you need to set the name as `Grid` and that's it. `<Grid Name="Grid"`

Comment: It works ! But is it normal that I need to click on the image before each move ?

Comment: But for `frog.Focus()`, I put it in the InitializeComponent :) Thanks again !